# Is this generalization of Dirichlet's test true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

*Dirichlet's Test for Series* is stated as follows:

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a monotone decreasing or increasing sequence that converges to $0$. Let $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be another sequence whose partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n$ is bounded by a given real number $M\geq 0$ for all $N\in\mathbf{N}^+$,i.e,$\forall N\in\mathbf{N}^+$,$|\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n|\leq M$, then$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\text{ converges.}$$

I'm wondering if the condition "monotone" can be ignored, i.e, whether the following generalization of Dirichlet's test is true:

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence that converges to $0$. Let $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be another sequence whose partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n$ is bounded by a given real number $M\geq 0$ for all $N\in\mathbf{N}^+$,i.e,$\forall N\in\mathbf{N}^+$,$|\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n|\leq M$. $$\text{Then, }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\text{ converges.}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof definitely uses monotonicity.

Try $b_n=(-1)^n$ and $a_n=(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: I am very sad to hear this news...

Comment: Sorry :( maybe the series you have in kind has more going for it.